# ASP.NET MVC export html table to excel not working

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, excel

I have this method here:

```
[Authorize]
        [HttpPost]
        [ValidateInput(false)]
        public void ExportCostMatrixExcel(string GridHtmlExcel, string GridCommunityExcel)
        {
            Response.ClearContent();
            Response.ClearHeaders();
            Response.BufferOutput = true;
            Response.ContentType = "application/excel";
            Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=Reliquat.xlsx");
            Response.Write(GridHtmlExcel);
            Response.Flush();
            Response.Close();
            Response.End();
        }
```

This takes me html table and converts it over to an Excel spreadsheet, when I try to open the file, I get this error message:

> Excel cannot open the file 'Reliquat.xlsx' because the file format
>   or file extension is not valid. Verify that the file has not been
>   corrupted and that the file extension matches the format of the file.

Why is this happening, you can see GridHtmlExcel here on the link below, its an HTML table with colspans, is the colspans messing it up?

https://jsfiddle.net/2nyjhpaz/3/

Comment: I'm not certain this will fix your issue, but you could try setting the content type to vnd.ms-excel: `Response.ContentType = "application/vnd.ms-excel";`

Comment: Ill try that now

Comment: No I still get the same error

Comment: Unfortunately this is a bit out of my depth, but you could see if anything here helps out.  It appears to be for a similar issue: https://www.codeproject.com/Questions/665344/Export-to-Excel-using-Response-ContentType

Comment: "This takes me html table and converts it over to an Excel spreadsheet" No it doesn't, it outputs a HTML file and gives it a misleading file extension. As it happens, Excel can read HTML documents, but perhaps there's something about yours it doesn't like. Open it in a text editor like Notepad++ and check there's nothing screwy about the output.

Comment: Try changing your content type `Response.ContentType = "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet";`

Comment: Honestly, I have had problems with this in the past.. and I am now using jQuery DataTables on all of my tables and that comes with the capability to export to excel without issue (at least so far with me)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In essence it looks like you're merely dumping the contents into a file and just renaming it to an XLSX. However, that extension follows a specific XML-based schema, and that's why it doesn't play well.

You have a few options:

1. Find a library that can do this for you - initial searches list a few but they're often fickle little beings.
2. Use something like [HTML Agility Pack](http://html-agility-pack.net/) to parse the HTML into a usable format and write it into an excel file. You might have to create an excel file manually, possibly using the [Office Interop](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/interop/how-to-access-office-onterop-objects) stuff.
3. If the excel format itself isn't that much of an issue, you could choose to write a CSV file instead (and can be opened by excel), using [CSV Helper](https://joshclose.github.io/CsvHelper/) - but you'd still have to parse the HTML.

Comment: I wouldn't recommend COM interop for server-side stuff. There are a few free code libraries around for .NET which will write an excel file in the correct format without actually having to interact with Excel itself. But other than that these suggestions are sensible.